# How to message or call someone to open the door?

Tags: sentence-construction

When I arrived at my friends' house, there is no doorbell, I want to message or call her help me open the door, what can I say?

> - I am here
> - I am outside
> - I am outside the door
> - I've arrived
> - Arrived

Which expressions are correct?

Comment: Can I just say "Knock, knock..." Cuz we are good friends, I hope to express it in a lovely way...

Comment: It's me, I'm outside your house. Can you let me in?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use all of the abovementioned expressions. They will all work. Though, some of them are not very idiomatic English. But if you're anything like me and like being short and sweet, I would recommend saying something like this:

> I'm at the door. Open up.